# Função não modifica a valor da variável

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby, redis

Estou tentando fazer um App que modifica um DB Redis, mas quando mando a função **conectar** a um usuário ele deveria fazer `Conectado = true`  e `UsuarioConectado = UsuarioQueConectou`.

Mas quando a função `Desconectar(DB, connected, usernameConnected)` verifica se `connected == true` ele deveria perguntar se eu quero desconectar.

E se `connected == false` (padrão) ele diz que já esta desconectado, mas quando conectei ele faz `Conectado == true`, mas ele não modificou.

E se eu uso `$connectado` ele dá erro pois não permite usar variáveis globais.

---

Meu código:

```
connected = false
connectedUser = "none"

def connectUser(db, conectado, usrconnected)
    puts "What's The Username"
    getusername = gets.chomp
    puts "What's The Password"
    getpassword = gets.chomp

    achou = false
    achou2 = false
    ...

    def disconectUser(connected, usercnt)

    if connected and usercnt != "" and !(isNul(usercnt))
      puts "Disconect ? (Y , N)"
      tmp2 = gets.chomp
      if tmp2 == "Y" or tmp2 == "y"
        connected = false
        usercnt = "none"
      elsif tmp2 == "N" or tmp2 == "n"
        puts "Ok ! Canceled With Sucess !"
      else
        puts "Unknown #{tmp2} -> Y or N !"
      end
    elsif !connected
      puts "Already Disconnected !"
    else
      puts "Error With Var's ! (Connected : Boolean)"
    end
  end
```

---

### Caso Precise Testar:

- Abra o Redis-server.exe por Primeiro
- Abra o App.rb (Abra com o CMD Caso Apareça um Erro E voce queira ver)

#### Downloads:

- [Projeto No Github](https://github.com/Vhenrique05/RegisAndRBConsult1/blob/master/App.rb)
- [Redis](https://redis.io/download)
- [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/downloads/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema clássico de ["parametros por referência ou por valor"](http://rubyblog.pro/2017/09/pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference).

No ruby os parametros das funções são passados por referencia, porém, quando você faz um assignment nessa variável o ruby cria uma nova variável com outro endereço na memória. Exemplo:

```
def change_value arg
  puts "#{arg} - #{arg.object_id}" # true - 3
  arg = false # a função = cria outra variável
  puts "#{arg} - #{arg.object_id}" # false - 5
end

connected = true
puts "#{connected} - #{connected.object_id}" # true - 3
change_value connected
puts "#{connected} - #{connected.object_id}" # true - 3
```

Uma solução seria guardar essa informação de connected e usrcnt no próprio redis ou ter uma classe que guarde essas informações em um objeto e manipular o estado desse objeto. Exemplo:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :connected

  def initialize name, connected
    @name = name
    @connected = connected
  end

  def connected?
    !!@connected
  end
end

user = User.new 'Joao', false

def connect user
  # .....
  user.connected = true
end

def disconnect user
  # .....
  user.connected = false
end

puts "Inicial: #{user.connected?}" # false
connect user
puts "Conectado: #{user.connected?}" # true
disconnect user
puts "Desconectado: #{user.connected?}" # false
```